# Get link to an IMAP mail from within Thunderbird?

Tags: firefox, thunderbird, imap, lightning

When dragging&dropping a mail from Thunderbird to e.g. Firefox, a link for the mail (in the address bar of firefox) is displayed. Any way to get this link from within Thunderbird?

(One can use the link to reference a mail from e.g. a Lightning task using attach - website on a task and by assigning imap:// to Firefox)

Comment: If you do "View Source" on the email within Thunderbird then it's in the title of the resulting window. Is that good enough?

Comment: It's the desired information, but I need to be able to copy the link to the clipbord for further processing/referencing \: